# Download non-hidden column in datatable in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, dt

In my datatable, I have hidden few column by using below code

```
columnDefs = list(list(
        visible = FALSE, targets = c(2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8)
```

But when I download the dataset in excel, even hidden columns are exported. Is there a way to download only non-hidden columns

Answer (score 2):

In `options`, try

```
buttons = list(
  list(extend = "excel", exportOptions = list(columns = ":visible"))
)
```

---

## EDIT

The above is for usage with the Colvis plugin, I think.

You can do, assuming your dataset is named `dat`:

```
hiddenCols <- c(2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8)
visibleCols <- setdiff(0:(ncol(dat)-1), hiddenCols)
```

then

```
columnDefs = list(list(
        visible = FALSE, targets = hiddenCols
```

and

```
buttons = list(
  list(extend = "excel", exportOptions = list(columns = visibleCols))
)
```